# count spark's saveAsHadoopFile be executed async?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I 'm running spark streaming task , in each batch, I 'll execute saveAsHadoopFile function.

My question is could this function be executed asynchronously?

that is, the io function will not block the next block's processing

Comment: Not sure what you mean, which language do you use. In case you use Scala, `Future`s or Akka actors might help with asynchronous execution; for Java `ExecutorService`s or also Akka actors. (I am not familiar with Python enough.) Could you give a more specific example?